# GTK Tree/ListView get selected Item

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mono, treeview

i am currently struggeling to get the selected item or even just the row number of the selected item in a Treeview. (C# GTK2.0- mono)

How can i get this data out from the "onActivateEvent".

list.SelectedItems sadly isnt an option.

Comment: What code have you tried? The TreeView has a treeView.Selection you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Yuuki.

First, the signal event you have to use is RowActivated.

Assuming that you have a ListStore called my_list_store, and your first columns have an Id and the name of a client:

```
protected void selectClientRow(object sender, RowActivatedArgs args)
{
    TreeSelection my_selected_row = (sender as TreeView).Selection;
    TreeModel my_model;
    TreeIter my_iterator;

    if (my_selected_row.GetSelected(out my_model, out my_iterator))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Client ID: {0}",my_list_store.GetValue(my_iterator,0).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}",my_list_store.GetValue(my_iterator,1).ToString());

    }
}
```

The .GetValue(my_iterator,0), gets the value stored in column 0, and so on.

I wish this helps you.